# Python Multiprocessing: Pool.map() seems to not call function at all

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

I'm quite new with multithreading so I'm sorry if it's basic.  I have some function that OCRs image files and I want to multithread the task.  The function does not return anything, but only saves the text of the OCR dataset.  The code is as follows:

```
start_time = time.time()
path = 'C:\\Users\\RNCZF01\\Documents\\Cameron-Fen\\Economics-Projects\\Patent-project\\similarity\\Patents\\OCR-test'
listfiles = os.listdir(path)

filterfiles = [p for p in listfiles if p[-4:] == '.tif']

pool = Pool(processes=2)

result = pool.map(OCRimage,filterfiles)

pool.close()
pool.join()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

When I run the code it seems like it gets stuck on `pool.map()`.  I ran it for 30 min which is way longer than the trial process took and it didn't produce on single output.  I tested my function OCRimage and it didn't seem like it entered into the function a single time (using `print(1)` as the first line of my OCRimage code).  I'm wondering if someone could help me out.  Thanks,

Cameron

EDIT (added OCRimage function):

The OCRimage function looks like this:

```
def OCRimage(f):
    #This runs the magick bash script which splits a multi-image tif into multiple single image tiffs
    process = subprocess.Popen(["magick", path + "\\" + f, path + "\\temp\\%d.tif"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print(process.communicate()[0])

    #finds the number of pages for each tiff file (this might not be necassary but the all files in directory python command could access files randomly)
    max1 = -1
    for filename in os.listdir(path+'\\temp'):    
        if (max1 < int(filename[0:-4])):
            max1 = int(filename[0:-4])
    max1 = max1 + 1

    text = ""
    for each in range(0,max1):
        im = Image.open(path + "\\temp\\"+ str(each) + ".tif")
        text = text + pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
    with open(path + "\\result\\OCR-"+f[0:-4]+".txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(text)    

    for f in os.listdir(path+'\\temp'):
        os.remove(path + '\\temp\\' + f)
```

Edit2:  Here are all the imports

```
import time
import subprocess
import os
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
countcpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

EDIT3:

Running just OCRimage(f) by itself works fine.  Instead of the multithreading code I just use this:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\RNCZF01\\Documents\\Cameron-Fen\\Economics-Projects\\Patent-project\\similarity\\Patents\\OCR-test'
for p in os.listdir(path):
    OCRimage(p)
```

Comment: instead of printing to stdout try printing into an output file :)

Comment: Are you suggesting that printing to stdout won't work for some reason?

Comment: The rest of the code won't print the OCR text file into an output file either.

Comment: Without a way to reproduce it's very difficult to help you, try to create a minimal complete reproducible example. Proving that that `filterfiles` is not empty, seeing the code of `OCRimage` (even if it only prints) and etc.

Comment: Writing to file doesn't work either like printing to stdout nothing happens and the file isn't created.

Comment: Where does `Pool` come from? It looks as though you're doing multiprocessing, not multithreading.

Comment: Yes sorry you are correct I'm doing multiprocessing

Comment: filterfiles is not empty I printed the contents of it.

Comment: This may be a Windows problem.  When I change multiprocessing to multiprocessing.dummy in the import it runs fine.

Comment: May I ask you to add the Windows tag to your question?

Comment: You don't need multiprocessing here, since your function doesn't do anything cpu-bound and only calls an external process instead, try `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` instead, you should see a speedup and I believe the child process won't hang (at least it'll be a bit easier to debug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that seems to show that the problem must be in your `OCRimage` function (see the **Windows** section below for the real problem):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def OCRimage(file_name):
    print "file_name = %s" % file_name

filterfiles = ["image%03d.tif" % n for n in range(5)]

pool = Pool(processes=2)
result = pool.map(OCRimage, filterfiles)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

**Output**

```
file_name = image000.tif
file_name = image001.tif
file_name = image002.tif
file_name = image003.tif
file_name = image004.tif
```

I recommend these changes to the start of `OCRimage`:

```
def OCRimage(file_name):
    print "file_name = %s" % file_name
    src = os.path.join([path, file_name])
    dst = os.path.join([path, 'temp', '%d.tif'])
    command_list = ['magick', src, dst]
    # This runs the magick bash script which splits a multi-image tif into
    # multiple single image tiffs
    process = subprocess.Popen(command_list,
                               shell=True,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = process.communicate()
    if process.returncode != 0:
        print "Image processing failed for %s: %s" % (file_name, errors)
        return
    # The rest of your code goes here
```

It is important to verify that the return code from the subprocess is zero. If it is not zero, you really want to look at the `errors` string.

**Windows**

When I ran the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on Windows, I got this exception:

```
RuntimeError: 
            Attempt to start a new process before the current process
            has finished its bootstrapping phase.

            This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
            forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    freeze_support()
                    ...

            The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
            is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
```

When I changed the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to this, it worked:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def OCRimage(file_name):
    print "file_name = %s" % file_name

def main():
    filterfiles = ["image%03d.tif" % n for n in range(5)]
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    result = pool.map(OCRimage, filterfiles)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So the problem is that when I don't multithread, OCRimage works fine

Comment: So at least the problem for me is that `result = pool.map(OCRimage, filterfiles)` doesn't work.  Even if I make `OCRimage(f): return f**2`.  I use python 2.7

Comment: Did you run the [mcve] at the top of my answer? Does it produce the expected output?

Comment: It does not.  I tried running your example.  I think it is a windows problem because my code ran fine on the linux cluster that it was designed for.

Comment: What is the output of `python --version` on your Windows machine?

Comment: I had to put the code inside a function to get the [mcve] to work on Windows. See my changes above.